# xUnit for Rabbit MQ mock connection in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core service which publishes messages in Rabbit MQ.

Below is part of my code:

```
public void PublishToOrchestrationRMQ(List<string> content,
                                        string queueName, string TraceID)
{
    if (content != null)
    {
        string OrderStatusQueue = string.Empty;
        string OrderStatusDLQueue = string.Empty;
        string exchange = string.Empty;
        GlobalConfig configData = new GlobalConfig();
        configData.GlobalSettings = _configServerData.Value.GlobalSettings;
        if (configData.GlobalSettings != null)
        {
            switch (queueName)
            {
                case "ASN":
                    break;

                case "SO":
                    OrderStatusQueue = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_SO_Orchestration;
                    exchange = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_SO_Orchestration_Exchange;
                    OrderStatusDLQueue = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_DLQ_SO_Orchestration;
                    break;

                case "WO":
                    OrderStatusQueue = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_WO_DM;
                    exchange = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_WO_DM_EXCHANGE;
                    OrderStatusDLQueue = configData.GlobalSettings.RMQ_DLQ_WO_DM;
                    break;
            }

            RabbitMqHelper rmqHelper = GetRabbitMQConnection(TraceID);

            try
            {
                IConnection RMQconnection = rmqHelper.ReConnectQueue();
                PushToRMQ(RMQconnection, exchange, OrderStatusQueue, content, TraceID, OrderStatusDLQueue);
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                rmqHelper.Cleanup();
            }
        }
        else
            _mLogger.Error(this, TraceID, $"No data to publish");
    }
}
```

This line

```
IConnection RMQconnection = rmqHelper.ReConnectQueue();
```

just connects to Rabbit MQ and is declared locally in the method.

My question is how do I mock connection for that line.

Comment: You need to mock the dependencies used by the method under test. What is `RabbitMqHelper`? How is it defined? how is it injected into the subject class?

Comment: There are too many unknowns in the shown code to provide a reasonable answer to your question.

Comment: RabbitMqHelper is from an internal nuget package and it just establishes a connection to RabbitMQ and I am only struck with this line. Can you let me know what are the too many unknowns?